# $ \mathbb{N} \sim \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : ~~ 10 \nmid n \} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm trying to create a bijection from $ \mathbb{N} $ to the set of natural numbers without numbers divisible by 10, meaning the set $ \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | \forall m \in \mathbb{N}. n \neq 10 \cdot m \} $. This is to show they have the same cardinality ( I can't use CSBT ).

**Attempt 1**: My Idea is to create a bijection such as $ f(1) = 1, ... , f(9)=9 , f(10)=11,...,f(19)=19,f(20) = 21,... $
so, naively, I wrote $ f(n)=
\begin{cases}
n+1, & \text{if } \exists m \in \mathbb{N}. n=10\cdot m\\
n & \text{else} 
\end{cases} $
However, this choice is false because it is not injective ( since $ f(11) = f(10) = 11 $  ).

**Attempt 2:** Define $ a_1 = 1 , a_2 = 2,..., a_9 = 9 $. Define by recursion the sequence $ a_n = a_{n-9} + 10  ,~~\forall n>9 $. The fact that I've created a sequence implies a bijection to $ \mathbb{N} .$

Attempt 2 works, but initially I wanted to give a specific bijection as I tried to do in attempt 1, do you please have any suggestions to such an explicit bijection?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your goal is to show that they have the same cardinality, the easiest way without Cantor-Bernstein's theorem is to simply say that $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : ~~ 10 \nmid n \}$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. This implies directly that they have the same cardinality.

Comment: If $n=a_k9^k+\cdots + a_09^0$ where $0\leq a_i<9$ then $f(n) = a_k10^k+\cdots + a_010^{0}$ is such bijection.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, You are right, it is way easier and elegant. I can't believe I forgot to use this fact...

Comment: @kingW3 Are you using generating functions?

Comment: No, I just noticed the pattern of the decimal/base 9 representation.

Comment: In terms of the mental model of the infinite hotel, one way to clear the rooms divisible by 10 from a fully occupied hotel would be to first move 5 -> 15, 15 -> 35, 25 -> 55, ... and then move 10 -> 5, 20 -> 25, 30 -> 45, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If attempt $2$ works then you can rewrite it this way for $n$ not divisible by $9$:

$$f(n) = 10\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{9}\right\rfloor + n  \; \mathrm{mod} \; 9$$

else:

$$f(n) = 10\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{9}\right\rfloor -1 $$